# Is it Possible to use Server Sent event (SSE) in JAX RS (RestEasy) with JBOSS 7?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy, server-sent-events

Good night!
The version of RestEasy present on Jboss 7 is possible to be change it for a new one that supports SSE ( like 3.5.1) ?
Any help will be really apreciate!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately NO. Read https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/AS710FinalReleaseNotes
JBOSS AS 7.1 is Java EE 6 compliant
The SSE was only introduced in Java EE 8 via the support for JAX-RS 2.1. 
RestEasy supports it in https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.0.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#JAX-RS_2.1_additions
Try moving to a newer version of JBOSS/Wildfly, the minimum is Wildfly 12
https://wildfly.org/news/2018/02/28/WildFly12-Final-Released/
In Wildfly 12, enable support for ee8 explicitly.